# Sharing SQL between native queries in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a few queries in one Spring Data JPA `Repository` interface that calls the same database function and joins to the same set of tables. The only difference between the queries is one of the join tables and one the columns being selected from that join table. Here's an example of two queries:

```
   @Query(value = "SELECT m.managerCode, s.employeeID, s.FullName, "
            + "s.employeeType, v.propertyValue "
            + "FROM User.fSysFunction(:binData) a " 
            + "JOIN User.vEmployee s " 
            + "ON s.employeeID = a.employeeID " 
            + "JOIN App.vManager m "
            +  "ON a.ManagerID = m.ManagerID "
            + "LEFT OUTER JOIN App.vPropertyValue v "
            + "ON s.employeeID = v.employeeID " 
            + "  AND v.PropertyName = 'BinID' "             
            + "where s.employeeType in ('set', 'ft', 'rs', 'wtr', 'wlt', 'ma') ",
           nativeQuery = true)
    List<EmployeeManagerDto> getEmployeeManagerDtos(@Param("binData") byte[] binData);

   @Query(value = "SELECT m.supervisorCode, s.employeeID, s.FullName, " // select col different
            + "s.employeeType, v.propertyValue "
            + "FROM User.fSysFunction(:binData) a " 
            + "JOIN User.vEmployee s " 
            + "ON s.employeeID = a.employeeID " 
            + "JOIN App.vSupervisor m " // a different join here
            +  "ON a.SupervisorID = m.SupervisorID "
            + "LEFT OUTER JOIN App.vPropertyValue v "
            + "ON s.employeeID = v.employeeID " 
            + "  AND v.PropertyName = 'BinID' "             
            + "where s.employeeType in ('set', 'ft', 'rs', 'wtr', 'wlt', 'ma') ",
           nativeQuery = true)
    List<EmployeeSupervisorDto> getEmployeeSueprvisorDtos(@Param("binData") byte[] binData);
```

I would like to avoid the SQL text duplication between the queries. How can I do that?

**Update**

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
 @Query(value = getQueryText("m.managerCode", "JOIN App.vManager m "
            +  "ON a.ManagerID = m.ManagerID "),
           nativeQuery = true)
    List<EmployeeManagerDto> getEmployeeManagerDtos(@Param("binData") byte[] binData);

 @Query(value = getQueryText("m.supervisorCode", "JOIN App.vSupervisor m"
            +  "ON a.SupervisorID = m.SupervisorID "),
           nativeQuery = true)
List<EmployeeSupervisorDto> getEmployeeSueprvisorDtos(@Param("binData") byte[] binData);

 default String getQueryText(selectColumnText, joinText) {
     return "SELECT " + selectColumnText + ", s.employeeID, s.FullName, " 
            + "s.employeeType, v.propertyValue "
            + "FROM User.fSysFunction(:binData) a " 
            + "JOIN User.vEmployee s " 
            + "ON s.employeeID = a.employeeID " 
            + joinText
            + "LEFT OUTER JOIN App.vPropertyValue v "
            + "ON s.employeeID = v.employeeID " 
            + "  AND v.PropertyName = 'BinID' "             
            + "where s.employeeType in ('set', 'ft', 'rs', 'wtr', 'wlt', 'ma')"
  }
```

This doesn't work of course but hopefully demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It can be many things, Is necessary to know the Database ER, but it can be because the different table has two rows that make the duplicated row, if every column has the same data, then you can use GROUP BY and enumerate every column from the select, like

```
" GROUP BY p.supervisorCode, s.employeeID, s.FullName, s.employeeType, v.propertyValue "
```

Or if the database is SQL Server you could just use DISTINCT like this

```
"SELECT distinct p.supervisorCode, s.employeeID, s.FullName, " 
            + "s.employeeType, v.propertyValue "...
```

Comment: I updated the OP so that it's hopefully more clear what I'm trying to achieve.